# Глобальный альяс условия выборки задаваемый при соединении

Tags: php, mysql

Есть например запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table  JOIN table2 ON (column1 = arg1) 
WHERE column2 = arg2;
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы, когда мы создаем соединение с базой(сессию),
то для текущей сессии передавался какой-то глобальный альяс? Когда **mysql** сервер встретит определенное сочетание символов, например - `column1 = arg1`,  этот альяс сообщал бы, что нужно заменить его на другое условие, например на `SELECT id FROM table 124 WHERE name = lastname` или  любое другое. В общем по типу того, как мы задаем параметр, например, `SET sql_mode = ANSI_QUOTES;` и в течение сессии работаем с заданным `sql mode`.

Есть ли несложный способ решения этой задачи?

Объясню для чего это нужно.
Есть движок в котором происходит масса запросов. Одним из 
условий в запросах, является комбинация товара по умолчанию. Что-то вроде: `column1 = arg1`. Я пишу модуль, который будет смотреть сессию пользователя, и выставлять для него комбинацию всех товаров, по умолчанию исходя из геопозиции.
Можно конечно везде в движке найти вхождения `column1 = arg1` и заменить их на `SELECT id FROM table 124 WHERE name = lastname`, 
но это мне кажется плохим решением. Задача любого нормального модуля - работать без вмешательства в файлы движка. Поэтому возникла такая идея.
Буду благодарен, если кто посоветует иной путь решения проблемы.

Comment: Попробуйте переменные пользователя, которые с `@`. делаете такую переменную и во всех sql запросах ставите условие типа `(@arg is null or column1=@arg)` сразу после коннекта к базе и установления геопозици делаете просто `set @arg=xxx`

Comment: А вообще это как раз задача движка, уметь выставлять в запросы некие глобальные настройки.

Comment: (@arg is null or column1=@arg)  так не пойдет. у меня как раз задача ничего в движке не трогать, а уж тем более во всех запросах выставлять замену. Задача то как раз в том,

Comment: Ну так вы это делаете один раз и забываете. а потом только переменную @arg ставите. по другому все равно не выйдет. просто замены не бывает. в SQL запросы изначально надо что то написать, что бы сделать универсальный механизм

Comment: Спасибо, понял. попробую переопределить метод метод в классе mysql и парсить каждый запрос на наличие искомой строчки.

Comment: Еще как вариант делаются view которые для SQL запросов кажутся обычными таблицами но на самом деле накладывают нужные нам ограничения. правда в mysql вроде кроме переменных или других таблиц не откуда взять информацию какие ограничения наложить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Просто замены не бывает, в SQL-запросы изначально надо что то написать, что бы сделать универсальный механизм.

Лучшее, что можно предложить - переменные пользователя, которые с `@`. Создаете такую переменную и во всех SQL-запросах ставите условие типа `(@arg is null or column1=@arg)` сразу после коннекта к базе и установления геопозици делаете просто `set @arg=xxx`.

Еще как вариант, создать представление `VIEW`, которое для SQL запросов кажется обычной таблицей, но на самом деле накладывает необходимые ограничения. Правда в MySQL вроде кроме переменных или других таблиц не откуда взять информацию какие ограничения наложить.